# Sources for different turnings during Hagba

Tags: minhag, synagogue, torah-reading

Some shuls turn have the magbia turn completely around while others have him turn first left then right (there may be still other minhagim).

Why the difference, and what's the mekor?

Answer (score 2):

I think it's all different ways of interpreting the Halacho as it's quoted from [מסכת סופרים פרק י"ד הלכה י"ד](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=33833&st=&pgnum=29) - which is probably the earliest Mekor.

> **יד.** מיד גוללין  (גולל) ספר תורה עד שלשה דפין ומגביהין (ומגביה) ומראה  פני כתיבתו לעם העומדים לימינו ולשמאלו ומחזרו לפניו ולאחריו שמצוה לכל האנשים והנשים לראות הכתב...‏

The Shulchan Aruch quotes it in [סימן קלד - סדר והוא רחום, והגבהת התורה](http://www.toratemetfreeware.com/online/f_01975_part_8.html#HtmpReportNum0003_L2) as:

> **ב:** **מַרְאֶה פְּנֵי כְּתִיבַת  סֵפֶר תּוֹרָה לָעָם הָעוֹמְדִים לִימִינוֹ וְלִשְׂמֹאלוֹ, וּמַחֲזִירוֹ לְפָנָיו וּלְאַחֲרָיו,** שֶׁמִּצְוָה עַל כָּל אֲנָשִׁים וְנָשִׁים  לִרְאוֹת הַכְּתָב וְלִכְרֹעַ, וְלוֹמַר:  וְזֹאת הַתּוֹרָה וְכו' תּוֹרַת ה' תְּמִימָה וְכו'.‏

He shows the writing of the Torah to those standing on his right and left and then he turns forwards and backwards.

The Kitzur in [סימן כג - קצת דיני קריאת ספר תורה](http://www.toratemetfreeware.com/online/f_00561.html#HtmpReportNum0022_L2) describes it slightly differently:

> **סעיף כ"ה:** 
>   לְאַחַר קְרִיאַת הַתּוֹרָה אוֹמְרִים חֲצִי קַדִּישׁ, וּמַגְבִּיהִין אֵת סֵּפֶר הַתּוֹרָה. הַמַּגְבִּיהַּ פּוֹתֵחַ אֵת סֵּפֶר הַתּוֹרָה שֶׁיִּהְיוּ שְׁלשָׁה עַמּוּדִים מִן הַכְּתָב גָּלוּי, **וּמַרְאֵהוּ לִימִינוֹ וְלִשְׂמֹאלוֹ, לְפָנָיו וּלְאַחֲרָיו**, כִּי מִצְוָה עַל כָּל הָאֲנָשִׁים לִרְאֹת אֵת הַכְתָב וְאוֹמְרִים וְזֹאת הַתּוֹרָה וְכוּ', וְגוֹלְלִין אֵת הַסֵּפֶר.‏

He displays it to his right and his left, forwards and behind himself.

Problem is, you cannot turn left-to-right without showing it forward or behind. So it cannot be taken literally - hence you have the variations you mentioned.

Comment: Since all texts place right before left, why are you saying that it's unclear? From all the sources you quoted it's pretty clear you show it to the right first, similar to how we proceed to the right in other places (turning to face the aharon while holding the Torah, Birkat Kohanim, and Bowing during lecha dodi ,for examples)

Comment: Additional point: Ashkenaz procedure inevitably gives the first view to those behind during hagbah (except during Simchat Torah?), not to the right or left, and certainly not the front. This might be supportive of the Sephardi methodology for hagbah, where the case is lifted in facing away from the body, showing it to those in front before those behind...